# How to use built in IoC container for constructing converters?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I created converter, into which through constructor injects some registered in app service. How should I configure Automapper to use this services on converter creation? I know that I should use `ConstructServicesUsing` inside MapperConfiguration, but in `Startup.cs` I don't have access to ServiceProvider.

Comment: Don't know to much about Automapper but if your Startup class has a method with a signature of `void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` it will get called and you will have access to the IServiceCollection obviously then.

Comment: Can you post a) the constructors of the Convertor? b) the registration of the dependent components? Not sure if this is easily doable

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in using an outdated way to register the service. I did it this way:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
{
    // Configuring automapper.
});
var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

New way (that uses default ASP.NET Core DI container) is in using `AddAutoMapper` extension method:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
{
     // Configuring automapper.
}, typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
```